# Centering operator between two underbraces

Tags: equations, amsmath

I'd like to center an operator between two underbraces containing a description of the above equation part.
I currently have this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\subsubsection*{Baz}\noindent
\parbox{\textwidth}{
    \begin{enumerate}
    \setlength{\jot}{10pt}
        \item [1.] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        \item [2.] abcde\\
        \begin{equation*}
        \setlength{\jot}{10pt}
        \begin{aligned}
            (a+b+c+d+e) &= a+b+c+d+e\\
            &= \underbrace{(a+b)}_\text{(FooBar)} 
            +
            \underbrace{(c+d+e)}_\text{
                (This is much longer than the part over the underbrace.)
            }
        \end{aligned}
        \end{equation*}
    \end{enumerate}
}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following document:

[image: Document]

I'd like the operator to be centered between the two parts of the equation.
I've found other solutions using `\parbox`es, but this looks hideous in my opinion. I dont want the text to be multiline, just a centered operator os it looks like this:
[image: correct]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allow me to suggest an alternative: Replacing one of the two braces by an `\overbrace`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\subsubsection*{Baz}\noindent
\parbox{\textwidth}{
    \begin{enumerate}
    \setlength{\jot}{10pt}
        \item [1.] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        \item [2.] abcde\\
        \begin{equation*}
        \setlength{\jot}{10pt}
        \begin{aligned}
            (a+b+c+d+e) &= a+b+c+d+e\\
            &= \overbrace{(a+b)}^{\text{(FooBar)} }
            +
            \underbrace{(c+d+e)}_{\mathclap{\text{
                (This is much longer than the part over the underbrace.)
            }}}
        \end{aligned}
        \end{equation*}
    \end{enumerate}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With regards to your original request, I don’t think there is any elegant solution that doesn’t require manual adjustments of the spacing you want surrounding the `+` sign. Of course, you could make a giant macro that calculates this spacing based on the sizes of the underbrace text, but this will probably become bulky and require you to input these underbrace texts as arguments. A manual solution is also likely to lead to more satisfactory results, in the long run, at the cost of more work. Here is one such solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\centerop[2]{\hspace{#1}#2\hspace{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\subsubsection*{Baz}\noindent
\parbox{\textwidth}{
    \begin{enumerate}
    \setlength{\jot}{10pt}
        \item [1.] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        \item [2.] abcde\\
        \begin{equation*}
        \setlength{\jot}{10pt}
        \begin{aligned}
            (a+b+c+d+e) &= a+b+c+d+e\\
            &= \underbrace{(a+b)}_{\mathclap{\text{(FooBar)} }}
            \centerop{1.3cm}{+} %adjust the number 3cm manually
            \underbrace{(c+d+e)}_{\mathclap{\text{
                (This is much longer than the part over the underbrace.)
            }}}
        \end{aligned}
        \end{equation*}
    \end{enumerate}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well I guess this is the way to go for this example, but in case there are more than 2 annotations this wouldn't work. I've seen documents (sadly pdf, otherwise I'd already know how) doing it with a lot of annotations and centered operators, so there must be a way.

Comment: @Domi Then perhaps it would be helpful if you could screenshot a page from one of these PDFs so that we can know for sure what it is that you want. `;-)`

Comment: Can't find it right now, but I've edited the screenshot so you can see what I mean.

Comment: The problem doesn't come up often, so this is definitely good enough. Still bugs me that there isn't something like `\centerop{\sizeoftextunderbrace}` though.

Comment: Updated it with a slightly simpler solution, but where you need to input a different value for the spacing.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{utfsym}
\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\subsubsection*{Baz}\noindent
\parbox{\textwidth}{
    \begin{enumerate}
    \setlength{\jot}{10pt}
        \item [1.] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        \item [2.] abcde\\
        \begin{equation*}
        \setlength{\jot}{10pt}
        \begin{aligned}
            (a+b+c+d+e) &= a+b+c+d+e\\
            &= \underbrace{(a+b)}_{\hspace{.02cm}\usym{2780}} 
            +
            \underbrace{(c+d+e)}_{\hspace{.02cm}\usym{2781}}
        \end{aligned}
        \end{equation*}
    \end{enumerate}
}
where  \usym{2780}=(FooBar) and \usym{2781}=This is much longer than the part over the underbrace.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Gaussler's answer, but with a few more suggestions for a better output, if you insist in underbracing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\ubracetext}[3][c]{{%
  \underbrace{#2}_{\mbox{\normalfont\scriptsize\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}#1@{}}#3\end{tabular}}}%
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
%%% a hack for the particular case
\begin{aligned}
(a+b+c+d+e) &= a+b+c+d+e\\
            &= \ubracetext{(a+b)}{(FooBar)}
               \makebox[1em][l]{\hspace{1.3em}$+$}
               \ubracetext{(c+d+e)}{
                 (This is much longer than \\ the part over the underbrace.)
               }
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

There are several issues with `\underbrace` so I usually recommend to define

```
\newcommand{\ubrace}{2}{{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}
```

(note the additional braces, so the entire object is treated as an ordinary symbol). But if you want to use text below the brace and get it breakable across lines, it's better to use a suitable command.

The command `\ubracetext` has an optional argument (default `c`) to choose the alignment in the split text and can be either `l`, `r`, or even `p{<length>}`.

For placing the + sign between the two, I'd simply gauge by eye. It would be possible to compute precisely the spacing, but how many of these objects will you have? In my opinion, one is actually too many!

Beware that, in any case, `_\text{text}` is wrong syntax. It just *seems* to work, but it could break. Similarly for `_\mathrm{x}`. Always use additional braces around complex subscripts or superscripts.

[image]

Comment: I originally posted a box solution, too, but it seemed artificial to me.